Delete all footnote/endnote numbers throughout a pdf using Pymupdf?
I am trying to delete all footnotes/endnotes in a pdf.  They all have a font size of six, while the rest of the text has a font size of twelve.
Example text:
"The Industrial Revolution marked a significant turning point in human history, ushering in mass production and urbanization."19 ("19" would be in font size six).
Text after running code:
"The Industrial Revolution marked a significant turning point in human history, ushering in mass production and urbanization."
This is the code I have so far, but is not working.
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

def remove_small_numbers(pdf_path, output_path):
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)

    for page_num in range(len(doc)):
        page = doc.load_page(page_num)
        blocks = page.get_text("dict")["blocks"]

        for b in blocks:
            if "lines" in b:
                for line in b["lines"]:
                    for span in line["spans"]:
                        if span["size"] == 6 and span["text"].strip().isdigit():
                            rect = fitz.Rect(span["bbox"])  # Get the bounding box of the span
                            page.add_rect_annot(rect)  # Add a transparent annotation to cover the text

        # Remove all annotations (which cover the small numbers)
        for annot in page.annots():
            page.delete_annot(annot)

    doc.save(output_path)
    doc.close()

# Example usage
input_pdf = "input.pdf"
output_pdf = "output.pdf"

remove_small_numbers(input_pdf, output_pdf)


Thank you, @KJ.  I will try that.  The font size is six based on looking at it in edit mode in Adobe Acrobat.  So that may be wrong or like you said not exactly six.
